# TypeScript for Node.js?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Is it possible to write server app using Node.js with TypeScript.

Are there plans in Node.js team to support TypeScript?

How to you think what kind of benefits it may bring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the docs of `NestJS` , You would see

Nest is a framework for building efficient, scalable Node.js server-side applications. It uses modern JavaScript, is built with TypeScript (preserves compatibility with pure JavaScript) and combines elements of OOP (Object Oriented Programming), FP (Functional Programming), and FRP (Functional Reactive Programming).

See [docs](https://github.com/nestjs/nest)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to write server app using Node.js with TypeScript.

There is a compiler that can compile TypeScript to ECMAScript. It is called `tsc` and you can find it at the [TypeScript homepage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Since Node.js can execute ECMAScript, you can trivially write a server app using Node.js with TypeScript by simply using `tsc` to compile TypeScript to ECMAScript.

You can do this with every language for which a compiler to ECMAScript exists, actually. [PureScript](http://purescript.org/), [CoffeeScript](https://coffeescript.org/), [CokeScript](http://batiste.info/CokeScript/), [Scala](https://scala-js.org/), [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), [Ruby](https://opalrb.com/), [Java](http://jsweet.org/), F♯, C♯, and [many many others](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js).

There's also [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/), a compiler backend for LLVM that compiles to ECMAScript. This means, you can compile any language for which an LLVM frontend exists, e.g. Rust, Swift, Objective-C, Go, C++, C, etc., to ECMAScript and thus write Node.js apps in them.

Also, you can use Emscripten to compile any interpreter written in Rust, Swift, Objective-C, Go, C++, C, etc. to ECMAScript, run that interpreter on Node.js and thus write your Node.js app in any language for which an interpreter written in C, C++, etc. exists.

> Are there plans in Node.js team to support TypeScript?

There is no need since you can already write Node.js apps in TypeScript and lots of other languages today.

> How to you think what kind of benefits it may bring?

The same benefits and drawbacks writing anything in TypeScript brings.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

1. Yes, you can.
2. It's already supported

Benefits

- Better maintence
- Better productivity
- Type Safe
- ...

**There's an [article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/typescript-with-node-and-express-js-why-when-and-how-eb6bc73edd5d) on Medium about.**